# Projecting OpenStreetMap raster base in other projections

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, epsg

I know that OSM WMS service works with EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913 
I need to have an OSM base layer projected in another Projection, for example **EPSG:32632**
Do you know some way to do this?
Even Reproject WMS service, or download new tiles for Geoserver.

Comment: While it is possible to cascade the services using Geoserver, you would be consuming a lot of resources. It's better to download the OSM data for your region, and host the services in your projection, yourself.

Comment: You can use gdalwarp (http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject to your SRS

Answer (score 1):

@Devdatta Tengshe gave the answer that works. Cascade the WMS service through another WMS that can do re-projection on-the-fly. It can be for example Geoserver, Mapserver or Mapproxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with ArcGIS 10.x you can use 'Basemap' option: File > Add Data > Add Basemap > OSM.
Than you right-click on Layers > Properties > Coordinate System  and change to yours.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks Michal,<br> but I need to use it in OpenLayers and so Native Projection of WMS needs to be in EPSG:32632